# .htaccess URL Redirecting giving 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lightspeed

I have a .htaccess file that is working fine on Apache server on Windows 7, but giving 500 Internal Server Error on LightSpeed Server. This is my .htaccess file:

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
AuthUserFile **********************
AuthGroupFile /dev/nullAuthName "Please enter your ID and password"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
order deny,allow

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /someFolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule /R/(.*)/ index.php?R=$1
```

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: I have no access to the error logs .. I have FTP access to my directory only.

Answer (score 0):

`Options +FollowSymlinks` will cause a 500 error if the server hasn't set `AllowOverride Options=FollowSymlinks`.

Comment: So should I remove this line `Options +FOllowSymlinks` ??